# Is inertia group always commutative?

Tags: number-theory, galois-representations

Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ for some prime $p$. $I_K$ is the inertia group of $\bar K/K$.

> Can we prove the inertia group is commutative?

Actually the case is: For some representation $V$ (finite-dimensional over $\mathbb Q_l$) of $I_K$, if $I_K$ acts unipotently(i.e. all elements only have $1$ as the eigenvalue), I need to prove that all elements of $I_K$ can be simultaneously triangularized.

If $I_K$ is commutative or its image in $\operatorname {Aut}_{\mathbb Q_l}(V)$ is commutative, then it's easy. How to get the conclusion?

Comment: Why would the inertia group always be commutative?

Comment: It isn't, try with $\Bbb{Q}_3(3^{1/3},\zeta_3)/\Bbb{Q}_3$ which is totally ramified with Galois group $S_3$ (it stays the same when replacing $\Bbb{Q}_3$ by $\Bbb{Q}_3(\zeta_{3^\infty-1})$). On the other hand the tame inertia $Gal(K^t/K^{ur})$ is commutative.

Comment: @Aphelli It would be more approperiate if you just post a counterexample.

Comment: *If the inertia group were commutative (or even if this question was undecided), how come it is not more frequently mentioned?* That’s why I believe that to even state such a question, you must have some sort of justification. Regardless, about your overall problem – consider instead the *wild inertia group* $I^+$, the (unique) pro-$p$-Sylow of the inertia group, and its image in $GL_d(\mathbb{Z}_l)$ (after choosing a stable lattice for $V$). Its intersection with $I+lM_d(\mathbb{Z}_l)$ is trivial (cardinality). Thus $I^+$ acts through a finite quotient. It’s unipotent so acts trivially.

Comment: As reuns wrote (and he also gave you a good counterexample), $I/I^+$ is the tame inertia group. Since it is commutative, you’re done.

Comment: @Aphelli I get it. Thanks for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $V_K$ be the ramification group, which is a closed subgroup of $I_K$. By Proposition 7.5.1 of *Cohomology of Number fields* (Neukirch-Schmidt-Wingberg) $V_K$ is a free pro-$p$ group of countably infinite rank, thus $V_K$ is not commutative. Then $I_K$ is not commutative a fortiori.